# Website files are hidden in FTP and need to move host

Tags: joomla, ftp, host, hosts

I'm new to Joomla and trying to help on a project.

I'm trying to switch host providers for my live Joomla Website.

I've successfully connected to FTP within Dreamweaver and the sites files are not displaying. Locally, I see the folder 'htdcos' with only 'contact.php' in it and only '.ftpquota' on the remote end. How can I access the websites files to back them to my hard drive to re-upload them to the new host?

Answer (score 0):

Use http://filezilla-project.org/download.php

Comment: So - the files generally wont show in Dreamweaver with Joomla?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used Dreamviewer's ftp-manager. I would suggest you to download needed files using FTP-client (Filezilla or any other), edit them localy and upload updated files. It works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FTP such as FileZilla http://filezilla-project.org/download.php Dreamweaver is not that much compatible with Joomla's architecture.

Most of the web hosting companies, provides a back-end (CPanel) where you can zip the website root folder and upload it to the site and extract them, that way its very easy to deploy your joomla website.